# sklearn: how to make fit and transform a feature selector in a GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am experimenting feature selection on my dataset and I noticed that I get different results between a) putting feature selection inside a Pipeline wrapped in a GridSearchCV object and calling 'fit', and b) call the fit_transform on the feature selector then apply GridSearhCV on the classifier, taking the fit_transformed feature matrix from the feature selector. Is it because the difference between 'fit' and 'fit_transform'? Not sure if I am making myself clear but here is the code for gridsearch:

```
fs=SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced',penalty="l1",C=0.01))
fs_params = {} #deliberately leaving these empty for comparison
classifier = svm.LinearSVC()
cl_params = {} #deliberately leaving these empty for comparison
pipe = []
params=[]
pipe.append(('fs', fs))
params.append(fs_params)    
pipe.append(('classify', classifier))
params.append(cl_params)
pipeline=Pipeline(pipe)
piped_classifier = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=params, cv=10,
                              n_jobs=-1)
piped_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

nfold_predictions=cross_val_predict(piped_classifier.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train, cv=10)

best_estimator = piped_classifier.best_estimator_
best_param = piped_classifier.best_params_    
cv_score = piped_classifier.best_score_ 
#followed by code to print scores
```

and the code for doing feature selection outside GridSearchCV:

```
select = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced',penalty="l1",C=0.01))
X_ = select.fit_transform(X_train,y_train) #line A
classifier = svm.LinearSVC()
piped_classifier = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid=params, cv=10,
                              n_jobs=-1)
piped_classifier.fit(X_, y_train)

nfold_predictions=cross_val_predict(piped_classifier.best_estimator_, X_, y_train, cv=10)

best_estimator = piped_classifier.best_estimator_
best_param = piped_classifier.best_params_    
cv_score = piped_classifier.best_score_ 
#followed by code to print scores
```

And for the first code, the scores I get are like:

```
P=0.31  R=0.17  F1=0.22
```

while for the second, the scores are better:

```
P=0.41  R=0.28  F=0.33
```

The only thing that I can think of may cause this problem is line A in the second code snippet, which calls fit_transform. Other than that, I think the two code snippets should be doing the equivalent task.

Any suggestions higly appreciated.

Comment: You are not using `X_` anywhere, which should be used in the input to GridSearch in second case.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant to ask is how do I put that as a part of the pipeline, like in the first code snippet. In the first case, the feature selector is in the pipeline, but I suppose the 'fit' method will be called instead of 'fit_transform'. In the second case, I deliberately do feature selection outside gridsearch so I can call fit_transform. But then I cannot do gridsearch on this feature selector. thanks.

Comment: When you call fit() on pipeline, fit and transform both will be called on each transformer (except last). Only the transformed data will be passed onto next transformer. `fit_transform()` is just a shorthand for `fit()` and then `transform()`.

Comment: For second case, use `piped_classifier.fit(X_, y_train)` and you will get more or less same results. And the post is very confusing. For second case, you are saying "code without gridsearch", but actually its code without pipeline. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Apologize for the confusion. I have edited the post. I have double checked my code and I am in fact using X_ in the second code snippet. I thought the pipeline should do fit then transform as well, but it is really strange that I get sharply different results... I am not sure which part could be wrong, can you suggest different ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should expect different results potentially due to [data leakage](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/Leakage)

In you second snippet, the gridsearch trains the svc on a slice of `X_train`however, the feature selection is trained on all of `X_train`

In the first example you avoid this problem.

This can reduce generalization performance heavily. However, it's unclear how you get the information on P, R and F. Did they come from a test set?

However, I'm not sure if this can explain the magnitude of differences in the metrics. At least your code shows the typical overfitting when using data leakage and that performance degrades when pipelining the feature selection.

You also might want to take a look at the [scikit-learn documentation on nested cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-nested-cross-validation-iris-py)

Let me add one important remark: In the second approach, you will fix the features you pass to your svc at the beginning. Thus the svc will use the same features on every fold. Whereas in the first example, the features passed to grid search may change from fold to fold!

Comment: Thank you, that should be the reason. The evaluation scores are obtained from the 'nfold_predictions' object in both cases, by looking for the average p, r, f1 across all folds. In both snippets I used 10 fold-validation. So if I have understood, in the first snippet, feature selection (FS) and classifier (CL) are both trained on 9 splits for 9 times and tested on the other 1 split, and the scores are the average of the tests on the 1 split. In the second case, FS benefited from data leakage, giving useful information to CL in those 10-fold validation runs.